# Database logon failed while using mysql azure

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure, crystal-reports

I am trying to print crystal report in PDF format , and on my local machine it’s working fine. But when I publish application to the server, it’s giving me the following error on Print button.
`Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.`
Below is my code in my controller

```
    public ActionResult Export(int Id)
    {
     ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
     rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/GcReport.rpt")));
     var query = rLAService.GetGeneralConsignmentById(Id);
     var querylist = new List<GeneralConsignmentDto> { query };
     rd.SetDataSource(querylist);
     rd.SetParameterValue("Id", Id);
     //rd.SetDataSource(rLAService.GetGeneralConsignmentById(Id));
     Response.Buffer = false;
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return File(stream, "application/pdf", "GC Report.pdf");            
    }
```

Edit
Ok, after digging throuh the problem, i found that error is `table name generalconsignment1` does not found. But problem is it is taking automatically instead of `generalconsignment`.now how to handle this situation?

Comment: Can you check db credentials? Perharps the local credentials are copied to the server.

Comment: connection is good..it is fetching the records from db